# Error inflating Binary XML file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to inflate custom class (scrollView) in xml then this error shows can anyone explain what is going on with my code please?

I'm trying to disable scrolling at specific point of scrolling then enable it again.

```
  partnerScrollView = (LockableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.partnerScrollView);


  <com.mibag.utils.LockableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/partnerScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

    </com.mibag.utils.LockableScrollView>



 08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mibag/com.mibag.PartnerListDetail_Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mibag.utils.LockableScrollView
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mibag.utils.LockableScrollView
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:381)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at com.mibag.PartnerListDetail_Activity.onCreate(PartnerListDetail_Activity.java:201)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    ... 10 more
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
    08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:580)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix it it was in this line:
 08-09 15:38:03.270: E/AndroidRuntime(22013): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
I have to add this constructor in the custom class.

```
public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```